# Remover style de un componente web LitElement y JS

Tags: javascript, css, html5, web-components

estoy trabajando con componentes web LitElement, y reutilizando un componente....Este componente es un select...
En mi componente principal (padre) tengo importado el componente del select a través de npm, este componente recibe un array de datos desde el padre...

En mi componente padre tengo un tab con tres pestañas, las cuales usan en mismo componente select...

Estoy implementando la funcionalidad de resetear una pestaña del tab al dar click y cambiar a la otra...

Analizando la funcionalidad del código del componente, observé que al  seleccionar un item del select, se le agregan estilos y una propiedad 'selected' a cada elemento(objeto) de array....

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo remover los estilos agregados en la selección del componente select?????????

Para quitar la propiedad select que se agregó al array tengo el siguiente código, pero no puedo remover el estilo agregado...

1.- Código para remover la propiedad select

```js
resetTabs(e) {
    if (e.target.selected === 0) {
      let select = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('#select');
      select.emptyLabel = 'Selecciona una cuenta';
      select.value = '';
      select.options.filter(item => {
        if (item.selected == true) {
          delete item.selected
        }
      });
    }
    else if (e.target.selected === 1) {
      console.log('Tab 2', e.target.selected)
    }
    else if (e.target.selected === 2) {
      console.log('Tab 3 ', e.target.selected)
    }
    this.requestUpdate()
  }
```

2.- Así se ve antes de la selección
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3.- Así se ve la selección
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4.- Así se ve al resetear el select...se queda con el estilo agregado(sombreado gris)...
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Seguramente puedes usar `item.classList.remove("nombre_clase")` pero debes saber el nombre de la clase, la cual no se encuentra en la pregunta, pero que seguramente puedes encontrar posicionandote sobre el elemento y pulsando el botón derecho del ratón sobre el para que aparezca el menu contextual, donde puedes seleccionar "Inspeccionar" para ver su codigo HTML en el inspector de objetos de tu navegador.

Comment: Estoy usando esto...pero no me funciona
item.selected.remove("highlighted")
item.selected.classList.remove("highlighted")

La clase es 'highlighted'

Comment: ¿y porque el selected?  Tampoco tengo claro, dentro del código que has puesto en la pregunta, donde debes ponerlo, pues no veo que desmarques lo seleccionado, sino que más bien lo eliminas con ese `delete` raro que veo ahí (debe formar parte del componente que desconozco)... si acaso ponlo debajo del `delete item.selected` y de este modo: `item.classList.remove("highlighted")` a ver si cuela

Comment: Es que no encontré como desmarcar el item seleccionado, lo que vi en el código interno del componente es, que cada ves que se selecciona un item (una cuenta), hay una función que agrega la propiedad selected al item seleccionado como true.  entonces por eso trate de eliminar la propiedad selected que hace referencia a que esta seleccionado (color azul)

Esto es lo que se agrega a la seleccion de cuenta:  class="searchable-select__option  selected  highlighted"
 ya logré quitar el selected con el delete pero no el highlighted

Comment: ¿has probado mi respuesta?  ¿que hace exactamente la función delete?  ¿estás seguro que la clase gris es la clase `highlighted`?  diria que no a esta última pregunta, y primero debes averiguar su nombre tal como he explicado en mi primer comentario para entonces usar mi respuesta y ver si lo consigues

Comment: tambien puedes mirar de averiguar la clase con `console.log(item.classList.value)` para que te las muestre todas y ver cual de ellas es la del gris para aplicar mi respuesta correctamente

Comment: Este es el código que agrega el selected y la clase
 getOptionClasses(opt, index) {
    const classes = [];
    opt.selected && classes.push('selected');
    index === this.highlightedIndex && classes.push('highlighted');
    return classes.join(' ');
  }

Answer (score 0):

> depende del estilo y si esta por clase y css o directamente incrustado
> en html, si esta por html lo que yo haria es cambiar cada style del
> elemento a un valor none o el que quieras asignar, por ejemplo:

```
var objeto = document.getElementById('intro');
objeto.style.backgroundColor = '#FF00FF';
```

> sino, si esta en una clase en css seria crear un nuevo estilo con una
> clase nueva en el css y usar el cambiador de clases de javascript:

```
objeto.classList.replace("nombre_clase", "nombre__nueva--clase");
```

> para esto logicamente primero debes averiguar la clase que tiene tu
> objeto.

Answer (score 0):

Desconozco el uso de ese componente, pero por lógica me parece que deberías poner, debajo de esta línea:

```
delete item.selected
```

esto:

```
item.classList.remove("highlighted")
```

pues según me parece entender por tu pregunta y comentario, ese `delete` lo que quizás hace es desmarcarlo y agregar esa clase `highlighted` al `item`, por lo tanto, si luego lo borramos con [classList.remove()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/remove) debería quedar bien.

Comment: Es justo eso, el delete hace el desmarcado y elimina como tal la propiedad selected que se le agrega al array de las opciones...la clase highlighted tambien se agrega cuando se selecciona una cuenta junto con el selected

Comment: tambien puedes mirar de averiguar la clase con `console.log(item.classList.value)` debajo del `delete` para que te las muestre todas en la consola y ver cual de ellas es la del gris para aplicar mi respuesta correctamente

Comment: aunque mucho me temo que no servirá, porque ahora que lo veo ese `this.requestUpdate()`  quizás se inmiscuye y recalcula las clases en ese momento y no cuando haces el delete... mmm... entonces lo veo mal para arreglarlo

Comment: En fin, si mi respuesta no te sirve espera otra de alguien que conozca ese componente a ver, lo siento.

Comment: Por lo que estoy aprendiendo ahora sobre webcomponents, estos encapsulan el DOM a su manera, y por lo tanto dudo que mi respuesta sea aplicable pues quizás el objeto item no es como yo creo que es, y no se puede acceder a sus clases con javascript de ese modo (que no lo se, es la primera vez que veo eso de los webcomponents, y parece interesante, pero no tengo ni idea aun, je)

Comment: He agregado la etiqueta webcomponents a tu pregunta para que quede más claro

Comment: Te lo agradezco, mucho....
ya trate de acceder al dom y ya tengo las etiquetas con las clases correspondientes, pero sigo sin poder eliminar la clase....Saludos...